# How to remove space between Div Tables

Tags: css, html

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B875/2/) there is a space between the two bottom divs. How do I go about fixing this issue?

The HTML

```
<div id="textbox"></div>
<div id="textboxSquare"></div>
<div id="textboxSquare"></div>
```

The CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

#textbox {
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    outline:0;
    height:25px;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 300px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#textboxSquare {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:25px; 
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #848484;
}
```

Comment: dont duplicate div id,s for starters use class

Answer (score 1):

Put all of those `<div>`s on the same line and it'll go away.

It's a problem with `display: inline-block;`

Here's a reference for ya:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

[Fixed your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B875/3/)

Look at that didn't even notice the other error:  Use an #ID only once.  The document will only be searched until the very first #ID is found, then it stops.

```
<div id="textbox"></div>
<div id="textboxSquare"></div>  <!-- This id="" must be unique to all others in the document -->
<div id="textboxSquare"></div>  <!-- This id="" must be unique to all others in the document -->
```

Use a class instead:  http://jsfiddle.net/8B875/4/

That fiddle also implements a different approach that uses a `float: left;` property but you'll have to adjust other things potentially if you go that route.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
float:left;
clear:none;
```

In the `#textboxSquare`:

```
#textboxSquare {
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:25px; 
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px solid #848484;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B875/7/)

Comment: including `float: left;` automatically implies `display: block;` and nullifies `display: inline-block;` all together.  I didn't mean to downvote I got clicky and now I can't find a way to remove the downvote.  So apparently you get an upvote instead lol :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use negative margins.

A good way to fight is the letter-spacing trick, where you set the letter-spacing of it's parent div to 0, and then reset it inside the inline-block div to `normal`

Answer (score 0):

Like said already don't use duplicate ID's. But that's not the problem. Use have assigned `display: inline-block`; to your DIV's. Simply remove this declaration and add a `float:left;` to these items.

Answer (score 0):

just remove space between `div`'s in your HTML like this:

```
<div id="textbox"></div>
<div id="textboxSquare"></div><div id="textboxSquare"></div>
```

or

```
<div id="textbox"></div>
<div id="textboxSquare"></div><!--
remove this space
--><div id="textboxSquare"></div>
```